# How can i fix this Weird Edit mode Shading Issue?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

https://gyazo.com/10e34ab61bdc020d43f44eb4ead883ce

i have this weird issue whenever i go Edit mode. can someone help me find the issue? or is it because of my GPU?

Fix!
Turning off "Cage on" of Subdivision Modifier Solves the problem of Z fighting.

Comment: it looks like overlapping faces, no?

Comment: oh its not overlapping sir

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/ or any other platform

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: It's Z-fighting of selection of original geometry vs preview of a modifier.

Comment: @Maru are you using AMD 6000 series GPU by any chance?